# How to print a list of tuples using a label in TkInter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter

I'm making a recipe handling program using Python and  TkInter. I have a list that contains tuples => (Ingredient, Quantity). I need to use a label to place it onto the screen. I want to eliminate the quotes and  the list brackets i.e `[]` but I want to keep the tuple brackets i.e `()`

```
mylist = [('a','2'),('b','4')]
```

I have tried iterating through the list but it just places the items one on top of the other and doesn't show everything.

**Expected Output**

```
Ingredients: (a,2), (b,4)
```

Comment: basically while looping through u have to pack it with the appropriate distance

Comment: If you're doing `myList = [('a',2),('b',4)]`, then there are no quotes in the data. The quotes are removed when creating the actual list. In other words, `myList[0][0]` is the single byte `a` not the three byte string `'a'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
', '.join(f"({', '.join(str(x) for x in item)})" for item in mylist)
```

Comment: Thank you, could you explain what's happening here, I'm not sure how this is working

Comment: The *fstring* is to join each element in the tuple using `', '` and enclosed the result within `()`.  The outer `join()` is to join each processed tuple (by the *fstring*) using `', '` in the list `mylist`.

Comment: I actually wanted to under what loops are doing in your code. I'm aware of the syntax used.

Comment: Sorry I don't catch what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The below code does get rid of the `''` in a and b:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

myList = [('a',2),('b',4)]

for index,item in enumerate(myList):
    Label(root,text=f'Ingredients: {item}').pack(pady=index+10)

root.mainloop()
```

But in this example i got it to be separated without the `''` but here the tuple no longer is a tuple but instead just a normal text that looks like a tuple. Give this a try (Answer by @acw1668 gave me a hint on this)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

myList = [('a', '2'), ('b', '4')] #your initial list
final = [] #making an empty list to populate later on

new = (', '.join(f"({', '.join(str(x) for x in item)})" for item in myList)) # removing the quote and creating a single word

item1 = new[0:6] #splitting into two tuples by slicing
item2 = new[8:14] #doing the same with second item

final.append(item1) #appending it to the final list
final.append(item2) #doing the same 

for index,item in enumerate(final): #looping through the list giving each item in the list a number
    Label(root,text=f'Ingredients: {item}').pack(pady=index+10) #placing it on the screen with label and packing with padx

root.mainloop()
```

Hope it helped, let me know if any more errors :D

Cheers

Comment: Can you check out cs1349459's answer. His answer is working well but I need to get rid of the quotes

Comment: his answer does not show on how to place the labels on screen? + there u have to use the same method over here to make them to a label? The second example here shows you how to remove the quotes and add it to the label right?

Comment: Yes I was converting it into a label, thanks anyway acw1668's answer has worked exactly how I needed it to.

Comment: hes master of the arts ;)

Comment: If you're doing `myList = [('a',2),('b',4)]`, then there are no quotes in the data. The quotes are removed when creating the actual list. In other words, `myList[0][0]` is the single byte `a` not the three byte string `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a custom `toString` method. It could be something like this:

```py
def toString(arg):
    string = "Ingredients: "
    for part in arg:
        string += str(part) + ", "
    return string
```

Comment: How can i get rid of the quotes ```''```

Comment: @rishi what do you mean?